# Request option calls in angular 2

Tags: angular

The following snippet is written with AngularJS, I would like to know the equivalent syntax for Angular 2 for this code snippet:

```
  $http({
       method: options.method,
       url: 'api/url',
       headers: options.headers,
       data: options.data || {},
       params: options.params
       })
       .then(success)
       .catch(error);
```

Comment: is this related to CORS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.request() method of the HTTP service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html#!#request-anchor):

```
http.request(url, requestOptions)
    .subscribe(success, error);
```

...where the URL is a string and `requestOptions` is an object with the [following shape](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html):

```
export interface RequestOptionsArgs {
    url?: string;
    method?: string | RequestMethod;
    search?: string | URLSearchParams;
    headers?: Headers;
    body?: any;
    withCredentials?: boolean;
    responseType?: ResponseContentType;
}
```

Depending on the structure of your `options` object, you might need to do some mapping from your structure to the `requestOptions` structure.

The `.request()` method returns an Observable. You then call `.subscribe()` on it and pass callbacks for `success` and `error`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following, that will work with your code sample :

```
import {Http, Request, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/operator/add/toPromise';
```

...

```
$http(request: Request): Promise {
   return this.http.request(request).toPromise();
}
```